# Displaying content from bulkLoader which is typed as MovieClip in Flex app

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, mxml, movieclip

I know this is somehow trivial, but I couldn't find appropriate solution so please help me :)

I am using bulkLoader to load dozens of SWFs into my Flex app, and all of SWFs are static (1 frame only). 'Everything' works fine, however, I'm not sure how to handle data from bulkLoader... I am getting MovieClip types for all of my SWFs, and I am not sure how to tell to Image or SWFLoader classes to use some of those MovieClips as source...

Thanks for any help really :)
m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source property of the Image or SWFLoader class only stores the location of the file (URL or local path) as a string. If you set this property the class tries to load that file (with bindable blabla)
So, you can't overwrite the source property with a movie clip.

Maybe you could cast the MovieClip to an Image component using
var image:Image = bulkLoaderMovieClip as Image;

bye,
tux